# Windows cannot find MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, path, mingw, atom-editor

I am trying to install MinGW and add it to my PATH on my Windows 10 computer (I need to be able to compile C++ in Atom, in case this is relevant to the answer). As far as I can tell, it is successfully installed and added to my PATH. I know it is added because when I change it to make it wrong, I get an error in Atom. Also, every tutorial I can find on adding it to my PATH says the things that I did. In cmd, when I type gcc, nothing happens. No output, no error message. Only a space, like hitting return twice in a text editor. However, in Atom, when I try to compile and run, nothing happens. No output or error message. [compile/run result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMqf9.png) The picture is of what happens when I try to compile and run.

Can someone tell what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Note: I am not a beginner, so my lack of output is not user error. Also, I can run the same program without a problem on a Mac.

Comment: Typing `gcc` (Note: use `g++` to compile C++ code) on the command line should spit out a message something like *fatal error: no input*. If you aren't getting an error, something is wrong very low down. type `gcc -v` this should spit out a nice long string of information about the compiler. If you get nothing here, you aren't getting the `gcc` you think you are, and I'll be smurfed if I know what you're getting instead.

Comment: @user4581301 Typing gcc -v does the same as gcc, where nothing happens and there's just a blank space. Is this a problem reinstalling might help?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your system is resolving `gcc` to a different executable than expected.

From a cmd prompt, try `where gcc` and if the path doesn't look right, then that is a good place to start.  If it does look right, then I suggest using a tool like sysinternals procmon.exe.  Set the filter to just `gcc.exe` and then run the `gcc` command from the cmd prompt and see what the procmon output is.

Comment: I did what you said, but I don't know what I am seeing. What am I looking for in the output?

Comment: What is the output of `where gcc`?

Comment: C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe. C:\MinGW\bin\ is what I added to my PATH.

Comment: Okay, (remember to be as specific as possible in your responses to help the person answering):  The next step is to run the sysinternal tool procmon.exe.  Try following these steps and see what you find: https://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/MZ2008024.aspx

Comment: Sorry, I thought I was being specific. When wasn't I? I followed the instructions in that link last night, but, like I said, I do not know how to interpret the output. No errors are jumping out at me, but I've never used this tool before, so maybe they're there and I just don't know what to look for. Thanks so much for your assistance!

Comment: No problem @tiffanie - you could be more specific by saying exactly what you tried and didn't work... I couldn't tell whether your first comment was a response to the `where gcc` suggestion, or the `sysinternals` suggestion.  
If nothing is jumping out at you with the sysinternals tool then you'll probably need someone to review it with you who's familiar with debugging this.  I'd look for errors loading files, or dlls, or messages about architecture etc.